"User matching query does not exist" When tried to follow a user
I am building a small social media website using Django, When I Click on follow button, I get this error saying: "User matching query does not exist." And showing the error here in the profile view function"user_object = User.objects.get(username=pk) this is the follow function in view.py file,
def Follow(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        follower_username = request.POST['follower']
        user_username = request.POST['user']
        
        # Get User model instances based on usernames
        follower_user = User.objects.get(username=follower_username)
        user_user = User.objects.get(username=user_username)

        if FollowersCount.objects.filter(follower=follower_user,user=user_user).first():
            delete_follower = FollowersCount.objects.get(follower=follower_user,user=user_user)
            delete_follower.delete()
            
        else:
            add_follower = FollowersCount.objects.create(follower=follower_user,user=user_user)
            add_follower.save()
    return redirect('profile',username=follower_user)


I tried to give try and except to the user_object, but it didn't work this is the profile view function,
def Profile_view(request,pk):
    user_object = User.objects.get(username=pk)
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user_object)
    user_post = Post_Upload.objects.filter(user=user_object)
    following_count = FollowersCount.objects.filter(follower=user_object).count()
    followers_count = FollowersCount.objects.filter(user=user_object).count()
    post_count = user_post.count()
    context = {
        "user_profile":user_profile,
        "user_post":user_post,
        "post_count":post_count,
        "following_count":following_count,
        "followers_count":followers_count,
        }
    return render(request, 'profile.html',context)


Post whole error message with full traceback. Also post your urls.py.

answer have already provided by Mahammadhusain kadiwala, couple of sugeestions though.

Please write function name in snack case like def follow and def profile_view
Have good naming. FollowersCount should be just Follower. (class names should be singuler and nouns)


I think your mistake is you trying to get object with username and value with pk so here .get() method raise un error "User matching query does not exist".
def Profile_view(request,pk):
    user_object = User.objects.get(pk=pk) # Need to correct this line

